# What is the article of clothing babies wear that covers the whole body and snaps between the legs called?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, ropa

[image: onesie]

In English, I call this a "onesie".  [Google Translate leaves it as "onesie"](https://translate.google.com/#en/es/onesie).  RAE doesn't have an entry for onesie, so clearly Google just didn't know what to do with the word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are dialectical variations. Since it's highly unlikely one person knows the terms all Spanish speaking countries use, maybe people from different countries can comment telling what word is used in their country. So here are the terms I've heard (some countries are from the RAE; I don't know whether these are correct or not):

- *Body* or *bodi*: España, Argentina y Chile ([example](http://www.kiabi.es/ropa-interior-bebe_204148))
- *Mameluco*: Colombia, Cuba, Uruguay y México ([example](http://www.buzzfeed.com/mikespohr/36-mamelucos-para-los-bebes-mas-geniales-que-conoz#.srOJ3Lm345))
- *Pelele*: Cuba, Honduras, México, Nicaragua y República Dominicana ([example](http://donacarmen.es/73-peleles))
- *Pilucho*: Chile ([example](http://listado.mercadolibre.cl/bebes-vestuario/pilucho-bebe))
- *Enterito*: Argentina y Uruguay ([example](http://cheeky.com.ar/bebe/enteritos.html)). Note: generally, an *enterito* also covers the legs.
- *Enterizo*: ([example](http://www.tejiendoperu.com/dos-agujas/prendas-y-otros-para-beb%C3%A9s/enterizo-con-zapatitos/)). Note: generally, an *enterizo* also covers the legs.

Some of these also describe a feminine garment. To avoid ambiguity it's best to add "de bebé": *bodi de bebé*, *enterito de bebé*, etc. Also, it may be the case a term is not used, popular or natural sounding in a given country but understood nevertheless. It's also possible that several terms exist in several countries but mean different things. Unfortunately for Spanish learners, it's not easy to tell!

Comment: *Body* is also used in Argentina http://cheeky.com.ar/bebe/bodies.html. An *enterito* usually has legs.

Comment: In Chile we prefer "_pilucho_". "_Enterito_" is also used but much less.

Comment: Yay, *body* is widely used in Chile as well.

Comment: Mameluco in Argentina is widely used for [**this**](http://listado.mercadolibre.com.ar/uniformes-mamelucos/), not so much for baby garments

Answer (score 4):

The name of that garment is "Mameluco" o "Pelele"

see this i.e.: http://www.bebe2go.com/products/mameluco-ba-by

or

http://www.parabebes.com/revista/que-es-un-pelele

Comment: [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=O6BsW4r) seems to list that as specific to Uruguay, Argentina and Cuba.  I see you're from Colombia.  Do you know if this is universal or regional?

Comment: Yes. In Colombia is very common. I used to work for a company that makes baby's garments and that is how they call it. As I understand it is used on all latinamerica but searching a little I found that in some places they also call it "Pelele". I do not know if they have a different name for it in Spain.

Comment: Hey, DGaleano! I've posted an answer with some terms I've heard in different countries. Maybe we can make a list with comments people post telling what word they use in their country. I believe I should add Colombia to "mameluco" and "pelele", right?

Comment: Hi @Yay. As always, good answer (+1). For Colombia just add Mameluco. Pelele is from some other places.